# mutate string into numeric, ignore alphabetical order of factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to recode factor levels into numbers using mutate function, but I want to ignore alphabetical order the factors are appearing in. There are multiple same values of factor levels and I want them to be assigned the number in the new column of the row in which they first appeared in the dataframe.
Example:

```
library(stringi)
set.seed(234)


data<-stri_rand_strings(20,1)
data<-as.data.frame(data)
data2<-data %>% mutate(num=(as.numeric(factor(data))))
data2
```

Expected outcome:

```
dat<-data2[,-2]
order<-c(1,2,3,2,4,5)
expected_result<-cbind.data.frame(head(dat), order)  
expected_result
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just create a new `factor` and set the `levels` as `unique` values of `data2$data` in your example:

```
new_fac <- factor(data2$data, levels = unique(data2$data))
```

The numeric values can be obtained:

```
new_order <- as.numeric(new_fac)
```

And this is what your final result would look like:

```
head(data.frame(new_fac, new_order))

  new_fac new_order
1       k         1
2       m         2
3       1         3
4       m         2
5       4         4
6       d         5
```

Or in your example with `dplyr`, you can do:

```
data %>%
  mutate(num = as.numeric(factor(data, levels = unique(data))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with a helper table that contains the row number of the first time a string appears in your table. I.e.

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)

# generate data 
data<-stri_rand_strings(20,1)
data<-as.data.frame(data)
```

Create helper table:

```
factorlevels <- data %>% unique() %>% mutate(order = row_number())
```

... and inner join to data

```
data %>% inner_join(factorlevels)
```

Output:

```
> data %>% inner_join(factorlevels)
Joining, by = "data"
   data order
1     k     1
2     m     2
3     1     3
4     m     2
5     4     4
6     d     5
7     v     6
8     i     7
9     v     6
10    H     8
11    Y     9
12    X    10
13    a    11
14    a    11
15    0    12
16    R    13
17    J    14
18    j    15
19    8    16
20    s    17
```

I am sure that there is a one-liner approach to this, but I could not figure it out right away.